# ADFS not returning domain groups (Also odd issues with get-aduser)

Tags: active-directory, adfs, claims-based-identity

I am trying to help someone troubleshoot an extremely odd AD\ADFS issue and am about out of ideas.

We are using ADFS to return the security groups (among other things) that a user belongs to.  If that user has a specific group, then we grant them access.  This is something that works on several other systems\environments.  In this case, ADFS is not returning any domain groups for the user (and I have checked a few users).

If I use

```
Get-aduser username -properties memberof | select -expandproperty memberof
```

nothing gets displayed.  If I do

```
get-aduser username -properties memberof | measureobject
```

it does give me a count of one.

Here's where things get really interesting.

If I check the user in ADUC, I see that it is a member of domain users, but that's it.  If I go look at the group in question in ADUC, it shows this user is also a member of that group (but does NOT show this group under memberof for that user.)

If I check get-adgroupmember it shows that this user is a member of the group that I truly need returned. The SID is the same for the user that it shows as belonging to the group as it is for when I use get-aduser to check the user in question (where this group doesn't show up).

Now, all of that aside - if I go and query ADFS - I don't get any domain groups returned for the user in question (neither Domain Users nor the other one that it SHOULD be in)

I assume this is LIKELY something security related, but am at a loss.

This same exact configuration for ADFS works absolutely perfect in several of my test environments.

Any advice\suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

`memberOf` shows you only:

1. Groups in your AD forest with a group scope of Universal
2. Groups on the same domain with a group scope of Global

It does *not* show:

1. Groups with a scope of Domain Local on any domain
2. Groups on other domains in your forest with a scope of Global

There's more: the Domain Users group is a bit odd. Members of that group are not usually in the `members` attribute of that group. User objects have an attribute called `primaryGroupID`, which contains the RID of that user's "primary group". The RID is the last portion of the SID. That's what makes them a "member" of that group.

All this means that you can't rely on `memberOf`. You can search the `member` attribute of groups for the user (using the user's `distinguishedName`):

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter { member -eq "distinguishedName" }
```

And if you need the primary group, find that separately too.

But there is a PowerShell cmdlet that does all this for you: [`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adprincipalgroupmembership?view=win10-ps)

It returns group objects, so if you just want the name, then pipe it into `Select`:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: Thanks - I have tried that, and it also doesn't return the "hidden\mystery" group.  This has to be security somewhere, but where?!  

Edited to add - this DOES return Domain Users.

Again, biggest issue is the fact ADFS isn't returning ANY groups at all.

Comment: Two questions: what is the group scope of your mystery group? And is it on a different domain than the user?

Comment: group scope is Global, type is Security.

Single domain

Comment: If you open the group in ADUC and use the 'Attribute Editor' tab, can you see the user listed in the `member` attribute?

Comment: Yes - just verified

Comment: Does this work (if you use your `distinguishedName`): `Get-ADGroup -Filter { member -eq "distinguishedName" }`

Comment: Ohhhh, that DID return it..... Please tell me that tells us something good, I am at my wits end with this.

Comment: So that just searches for groups that have the user in their `member` attribute. But I thought `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` includes that. I don't know why the difference.